# How to output java -jar errors to a text/log file?

Tags: java, windows, command

i have googled my heart out! I am trying to figure out how to output any errors a java class might give when executing java from the Windows command line.

For instance

```
java -jar class.jar <someFile.file>
```

if that line throws any errors, i want them to be stored into a text file for later reviewing.

I tried

```
java -jar class.jar <someFile.file> >> log.txt
```

But despite throwing errors the log.txt file is empty.

Thanks all!

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/110930

Comment: *"i have googled my heart out!"* Better to mention 1) What search terms were used. 2) Some of the top links found on those terms. 3) Why they did not suit the need.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use:

```
java -jar class.jar <someFile.file> 2>> log.txt
```

The 2 redirects the error stream.

Comment: I thank you greatly! Never knew that after all the batch files i wrote :(

And the search terms i used were "Output java -jar errors" and they didnt hold my answer. Nothing even close. Would have never thought to use redirect error stream. Thank you so much @thedayofcondor!

Comment: This answer was very useful. In testing however, I found the "2" outputs EVERYTHING, not just errors.

Comment: The `2>>` only logs `stderr` to the file, `stdout` should be visible on the console. It may be your jar prints its output as well to `stderr`?

Answer (score 1):

or you can use bat file to easily direct all output to a text file 
in command prompt

C:> something.bat > console_output.txt

Comment: I tested this. For some reason this doesnt output/log ANY of the java.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it like this to running it background

```
javaw -jar yourjarfile.jar >>yourlogfile.txt 2>&1
```

Try the one below if you want to run it on cmd session.

```
java -jar yourjarfile.jar >>yourlogfile.txt 2>&1
```