# Selenium JAR test case stops when reaching js commands

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, firefox, sharepoint

I made a test script for our company using Selenium JUnit, which works fine in **my account** in the company's network. But when other employees run the script it stops when it reaches JavaScript part of the code.

I found out locators for each Sharepoint element are different in different accounts,like `#ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_nameInput` is `#ctl01_PlaceHolderMain_nameInput` in other account, and that's why they are not reachable using my code. But how can I fix it?

We use Firefox as webbrowser and users need authentication to run the test case (HTTPS page).

I would be appreciated if anyone could help me with this.

The Script looks like this:

```
    WebElement NewPage;
    NewPage= wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("#mp1_0_2_Anchor")));
    NewPage.click();
    Thread.sleep(5000);
//Error appears after execution of the following lines
    if (driver instanceof JavascriptExecutor) {
        ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(""
                + "var tBox= document.querySelector('.ms-dlgFrame').contentDocument.querySelector('#ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_nameInput');"
                + "tBox.setAttribute('value','Testcase 13.1');"
                + "var btn= document.querySelector('.ms-dlgFrame').contentDocument.querySelector('#ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_createButton');"
                + "btn.click();"
                );
    }
```

Here is the Html code for iFrame>

```
<div id="s4-workspace" style="height: 175px; width: 390px; overflow-y: auto;">
    <div id="s4-bodyContainer">
        <div id="s4-titlerow" class="s4-pr s4-notdlg s4-titlerowhidetitle ms-titlerowborder" style="width: 372px;">
            <div class="s4-title s4-lp">
                <div class="s4-title-inner">
                    <table class="s4-titletable" cellspacing="0">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="s4-titlelogo">
                                    <a id="ctl00_onetidProjectPropertyTitleGraphic" href="/en/News/" target="_blank">
                                        <img id="ctl00_onetidHeadbnnr2" name="onetidHeadbnnr0" src="/_layouts/images/siteIcon.png" alt="News" style="border-width:0px;">
                                    </a>
                                </td>
                                <td class="s4-titletext">
                                    <h1 name="onetidProjectPropertyTitle">

                                            <a id="ctl00_PlaceHolderSiteName_onetidProjectPropertyTitle" href="/sv/News/" target="_blank">News</a>

                                    </h1>
                                    <span id="onetidPageTitleSeparator" class="s4-nothome s4-bcsep s4-titlesep"><span><span style="height:11px;width:11px;position:relative;display:inline-block;overflow:hidden;"><img src="/_layouts/images/fgimg.png" alt=":" style="border-width:0px;position:absolute;left:-0px !important;top:-585px !important;"></span></span> </span>
                                    <h2>

New Page

                                    </h2>
                                    <div class="s4-pagedescription" tabindex="0">

                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td class="s4-socialdata-notif">

                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="s4-topheader2" class="s4-pr s4-notdlg">
                <a name="startNavigation"></a>
                <div id="s4-searcharea" class="s4-search s4-rp">
```

After reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13215348/how-to-output-java-jar-errors-to-a-text-log-file), I could capture the error log below:

> Blockquote
>   JUnit version 4.12
>   .E
>   Time: 44,583
>   There was 1 failure:
>   1) testId1331(ID131)
>   org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: TypeError: tBox is null
>   Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:43:45 -0700'
>   System info: host: 'AOS391', ip: 'xxx', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_111'
>   Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
>   Capabilities [{rotatable=false, raisesAccessibilityExceptions=false, marionette=true, firefoxOptions={args=[], prefs={}}, appBuildId=20170125094131, version=, platform=XP, proxy={}, command_id=1, specificationLevel=0, acceptSslCerts=false, processId=14564, browserVersion=51.0.1, platformVersion=6.1, XULappId={ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}, browserName=firefox, takesScreenshot=true, takesElementScreenshot=true, platformName=windows_nt}]
>   Session ID: 324f9226-d3a0-4285-9128-c899ddc6bca6
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:127)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:93)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:42)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:163)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:601)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.executeScript(RemoteWebDriver.java:537)
>       at ID131.testId1331(ID131.java:63)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>       at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
>       at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
>       at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
>       at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
>       at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
>       at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
>       at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
>       at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.runMain(JUnitCore.java:77)
>       at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.main(JUnitCore.java:36)
>       at ID131.main(ID131.java:143)

FAILURES!!!
Tests run: 1,  Failures: 1

Comment: Can you please post the error appeared.

Comment: We can provide better assistance if you share your code and any messages that appear when it stops.

Comment: @vijayraj34 Thank you for your reply I have updated the post with error log and code.

Comment: @MarkLapierre Thank you for your reply I have updated the post with error log and code.

Comment: The error suggests the input field doesn't exist, or at least can't be found using the locators specified. Have you tried inspecting the DOM at the point the error occurs? Could you include the HTML as it appears when the error occurs?

Comment: @MarkLapierre The locator exists in DOM and I can locate other HTML locators in the page. But it can't locate Sharepoint elements when the code runs in other accounts, while we're all in the same network with the same rights and privileges.

Comment: @AlanD Could you please show us the HTML as it appears when the error occurs?

Comment: Ok. So the ids change. This is why I keep asking you to *share the HTML*. If you do that we can help you create an appropriate locator. Maybe you just need the input field inside the .ms-dlgFrame. But you're the only who can figure that out unless you *share the HTML*

Comment: @MarkLapierre Thank you! Now html code added.

Comment: Almost. Looks like you've posted the source HTML, not the HTML as it appears in the DOM at the point the error occurs. I.e., we need the dynamic HTML, not just the static HTML as it initially appears. If you open the page in your browser's developer tools you'll get the HTML we need.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear why you're using Javascript instead of the equivalent Java using the Selenium api. What happens if you try this:

```
WebElement NewPage;
NewPage= wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("#mp1_0_2_Anchor")));
NewPage.click();
Thread.sleep(5000);

//Error appears after execution of the following lines

WebElement tBox = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".ms-dlgFrame #ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_nameInput"));
tBox.clear();
tBox.sendKeys("Testcase 13.1");
WebElement btn = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".ms-dlgFrame #ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_createButton"));
btn.click();
```

Comment: It is also apploicable to use the methos you mentioned, but it doen't work in either ways.  I have updated the question a bit, could you plkease take a look?