# Logging output from executable

Tags: linux, executable

Is it possible in linux to start a program `./program` and everything it outputs gets written to a output.txt file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to output java -jar errors to a text/log file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13215348/how-to-output-java-jar-errors-to-a-text-log-file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about `./program > /tmp/mylogfile.txt 2>&1`

sending everything to the `/tmp/mylogfile.txt` file.

The `>` is a *redirection* of standard out (stdout) and the `2>&1` redirects standard error (stream file descriptor 2) to standard out (stream file descriptor 1)

Comment: Works like a charm but it stopped printing it on the actual console, can I make it console + file?

Comment: To answer your first point, investigate 'tee'. To answer your second point, not so easy, but I'm sure there's a solution out there using the 'date' utility and perhaps a script to pipe (not redirect) into

Comment: Wdym investigate 'tee'?