# On modal window opening application closes unexpectedly

Tags: java, javafx

I successfully execute jar file until I click to open modal window. Upon click event, the application closes unexpectedly. 
I can't diagnose what caused such problem?

**Source code:**

```
public void multipleEntryWindow(Event event, String page_src, String title) throws IOException {
    Stage commonEventStage = new Stage();
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(page_src));

    Parent root = loader.load();

    commonEventStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    commonEventStage.setTitle(title);
      commonEventStage.show();
    commonEventStage.setResizable(true);
}
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Without seeing your code, it is impossible to determine the reason for the hangup.

Comment: when click on button,this function will be called.I need two modal windows by click on same button.Even Though,If i open one modal window,jar file is closed automatically and also heap size is increases.

Comment: We can't help you until you post stacktrace what you get. How to log errors? See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13215348/how-to-output-java-jar-errors-to-a-text-log-file. Please update your post.